# Adding empty pages to fill up a book page quota

Tags: blank-page

I am writing a book and have already made contract for *x* pages with the printing company, so I want to create a PDF containing *x* pages. However, say that I only have material enough to fill *x − y* pages. Is there some package or simple hack available for adding *y* empty pages at the end of the document? I.e. I want to add empty pages until the latest added page is page number *x*.

Comment: You could add `clearpage\null` the appropriate number of times. (And add `\pagestyle{empty}` after the first `\clearpage\null`.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this using a simple loop.

The following code will ensure the document to be e.g. 100 pages in size:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\emptypages[1]{%
    \loop\ifnum\value{page}<#1\relax
        \clearpage
        \null
        \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \repeat
    \clearpage
}
\AtEndDocument{\emptypages{100}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

[The memoir package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/) provides the `\leavespergathering{}` command for a purpose closely related to yours. *Ipsis literis* from the manual:

> The command `\leavespergathering{`*num*`}` ensures that there will be
>   exactly the right number of pages output to make a complete set of
>   gatherings of *num* leaves (2× *num* pages) each --- if necessary blank
>   pages will be output at the end to make up the correct tally. If *num*
>   is less than two (the default) then no additional pages will be
>   output.

Thus, to fill to 84 pages, for example, you would use `\leavespergathering{42}`