# Create empty dummy pages to expand section to a certain number of pages

Tags: pdftex

I am writing my Master's Thesis and have planned the number of pages I want to write for each chapter. To get an idea of how much everything will be including title page, references, appendices etc I tried to tell LaTeX to expand each section with empty pages. I tried the approach from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25033/adding-empty-pages-to-fill-up-a-book-page-quota) and changed

```
\AtEndDocument{\emptypages{100}}
```

to

```
\AtEndSection{\emptypages{some_value}}
```

Interestingly, this seems to work for some sections, but not for all.

1. Is this the right approach?
2. If yes, do you have an idea what goes wrong with some sections? If not, can you tell me the right approach?

My document's structure looks like this:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{my_style_package}

\newcommand\emptypages[1]{%
\loop\ifnum\value{page}<#1\relax
    \clearpage
    \null
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
\repeat
\clearpage
}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\include{sections/titlepage}

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}
\tableofcontents 
\clearpage

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{section}{\numberline{}Abstract}{}{}}
\include{sections/abstract}

\pagestyle{plain}
\setcounter{page}{1}    

\include{sections/sec1}
\AtEndSection{\emptypages{x}}   

\include{sections/sec2}
\AtEndSection{\emptypages{x}}   

\include{sections/sec3}
\AtEndSection{\emptypages{x}}   

\include{sections/sec4}
\AtEndSection{\emptypages{x}}   

\include{sections/sec5}
\AtEndSection{\emptypages{x}}               

\include{sections/sec6}
\AtEndSection{\emptypages{x}}   

\cleardoublepage
\pagestyle{empty}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{section}{\numberline{}References}{}{}}
\printbibliography  

\appendix
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{section}{\numberline{}Appendix}{}{}}
\include{sections/appendix}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not use `\lipsum` from `lipsum` package?

Comment: Sorry to say but this is just the kind of thing we all do to avoid actually starting work. In any case, whatever you plan, you will not end up with the planned number of pages in each chapter because things never actually turn out like that. (Actually, I've never heard of anybody planning the number of pages per chapter.) It is quite possible that the planned number of chapters will change - never mind the number of pages in each one. You really shouldn't even be thinking about the format much until you've got the content, except insofar as keeping it flexible will make the formatting easier.

Comment: If it *only* about getting the page numbering right (for the ToC, say), you can just set the `page` counter to suit your needs...

Answer (score 2):

I would do it by using the [`lipsum`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) package

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum} % To include dummy text "lorem ipsum..."

\begin{document}

\section{My section one}
\lipsum % this will give you a little more that one page for a4 paper

\section{My section two}
\lipsum[1-23] % the numbers indicate how long the dummy text will be
              % So it can be longer if you want.

\section{My section three}
\lipsum[1-5] % the numbers indicate how long the dummy text will be


\end{document}
```

You can have this text separated in other files and use `\input{}` to include them.

This way you will get no only the amount of pages you want to see, but it would give you a feeling of how the text will look like when changing fonts
and styles, a feature that you can't appreciate by just looking empty blank pages.

I hope it helps!

Comment: **Remark:** The text above produces a 7 page PDF

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
\documentclass [12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcommand{\dudpage}[1]{\clearpage\null\vfill\begin{center}#1\end{center}\clearpage}
\newcommand{\myrepeat}[2]{\foreach \n in {1,...,#1}{#2}}

\begin{document}

\dudpage{This will leave one dud page with\\this label\\at the bottom}

\myrepeat{12}{\dudpage{This will leave 12 dud pages of thesis\\with this label at the bottom}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code produces 13 instead of 12 pages.

Comment: Yes 1+12 = 13 (I gave two examples, one producing one page, and another 12)